# Break if Newton's method is not convergent

Tags: newtons-method, convergence

I'm trying to implement Newton's method for polynomials to find zero of function. But I must predict case when function hasn't a root. I'm wondering how can I detect moment when the method becomes divergent and then stop procedure?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What language are you using and what did you attempt so far?

Comment: I'm using c++. I implemented Newton's method and additionally I use Sturm's theorem to specify the interval where the root can be, but now I need to consider case where there is no zero of function.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the root is not found after 10 iterations, then the initial point was bad. To be safe take 15 or 20 iterations. Or check after 5-10 iterations for quadratic convergence, measured by the function value decreasing from iteration to iteration faster than by a factor of 0.25.

Restart in a bad case with a different point.